# i want to make an array int with size 500 and fill

Tags: java, arrays

I want to make an array of int with size 500 and fill this in with;

- 0,1,2,...,499
- 1,2,3,...,500
- 500,499,498,...,1

  ```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  int[] numbers = new int[500];

   for(int i=0; i<500; i++) {
     System.out.println(numbers[i]);
  }
  ```

I know I need to do this with a for loop but I can't get the right code yet. Can anybody help me please?

Comment: In the loop, actually assign a value to the i-th array element: `numbers[i] = ...`.

Comment: What is the `F` in front of your loop, and why do you have a `}` after it (after the one that's supposed to be there)?

Comment: @AndyTurner: We don't know that that `F` and `}` aren't in the OP's code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign a value to each array-element

```
int[] numbers = new int[500];

for(int i=0; i<500; i++) {
   numbers[i] = i;
   System.out.println(numbers[i]);
}


int[] numbers2 = new int[500];

for(int i=500; i>0; i--) {
   numbers2[i-1] = i;
   System.out.println(numbers2[i-1]);
}
```

Comment: thank you!. How can i adjust the code so that it will go from 500,499,498...,1 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop for each case.

```
for(int i=0; i<500; i++) 
{
  numbers[i] = i;//0,1,2,...,499
}


int j = 0;
for(int i=500; i > 0; i--) 
{
  numbers[j++] = i;//500,499,498,...,1
}


for(int i=1; i<=500; i++) 
{
  numbers[i-1] = i;//1,2,3,...,500
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fill both in single for loop

```
    int[] numbers = new int[500];
    int[] numbers2 = new int[500];
    for(int i=0; i<500; i++) {
       numbers[i] = i + 1;
       numbers2[i] = 500 - i;
    }
```

and just for printing purpose

```
    for(int i=0; i<500; i++) {
       System.out.print(numbers[i]+" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    for(int i=0; i<500; i++) {
        System.out.print(numbers2[i]+" ");
    }
```